# Retrofit equivalent of a post request

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I have received this endpoint from backend team, but I can't implement it in Retrofit, please note there is duplicated tags[] field, backend people say it's correct :

[image]

I tried something like this, but it's not submitting tags:

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/submit")
    Call<ResponseBody> postDocument(
            @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> f1,
            @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> f2,
            @Part("id") RequestBody id,
            @Part("emails") List<RequestBody>  emails,
            @Part("tags") ArrayList<String> tags_1,
            @Part("tags") ArrayList<String> tags_2,
            @Part("email") RequestBody email
            );
```

Comment: can you click on the "raw" tab and paste the content here?

Comment: pass list of `RequestBody` in the `tags` field

Comment: Since it's form data, shouldn't user @Field instead of @Part?

Comment: It's multipart I can't use @Field